# Unusual Output in Nginx Status: Seeking Insights on Empty Strings in Process Information

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, systemd

My Nginx server `(Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)` is operating as expected, and I am not aware of any issues. However, I have noticed an unusual output in the status information:

```
sudo systemctl status nginx
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-02-09 11:16:54 CET; 4 days ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 776 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 874 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 879 (nginx)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 14170)
     Memory: 15.6M
        CPU: 801ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─   879 "nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;"
             ├─320285 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─320286 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             ├─320287 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""
             └─320288 "nginx: worker process" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" ""

Feb 09 11:16:54 hostname systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Feb 09 11:16:54 hostname systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

While the Nginx server is functioning correctly, the output includes empty quotation marks ("""""") in the process information, which appears unusual. I would appreciate any insights into why these empty strings are present in the status output.

Edit:

output of `psauxwww|grep 320285`

```
ps auxwww|grep 320285
www-data  320285  0.0  0.0  27284  7860 ?        S    Feb13   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

Comment: What is the output of `ps auxwww|grep <pid>` where <pid> is the PID from the status?

Comment: @djdomi I added the output as edit to the question

Comment: what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: sry, also added to the original question.. its 22.04 LTS

Comment: Well, I got the same output on freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04. So it is a normal output but something was changed in Ubuntu because I don't see the same behaviour on Debian 12.

Comment: On my other self hosted servers, I also got the same output. But in some way disturbs me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nginx` changes its process title by overwriting `argv` array and the following `environ` array directly. I would consider it a bit dirty approach but `nginx` was developed originally for FreeBSD and had to emulate `setproctitle` on Linux on its own. This code hasn't changed since 2005.

Because the string `nginx: worker process` is shorter than the original program name `/usr/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'` the remainder of the string is overwritten by `nginx` with zeros but `systemctl status` still shows all extra zeros as `""`. I suspect this behaviour changed later because I don't observe it with Debian 12 which runs `systemd` 252 vs Ubuntu 22.04 `systemd` 249.